# How to deploy laravel at subdomain?

Tags: laravel

I deploy laravel1 app on a sharing host. the content of public folder is in public_html and index.php is referring to laravel1 folder placed in root. It's working good, no errors. now I do this method for laravel2 app but this time, it's for a subdomain. laravel2 public content -> subdomain public folder. when go to subdomain, home page loaded successfully but when trying the other routes, like:"sub.example.com/posts" it just throw 404 error and it's not the default laravel 404 page, it's from server.
Also this happens when put public content of laravel2 app in "public_html/other-apps/lara2/". This time index.php is referring like this: "/../../../vendor/autoload.php" but when go to path "example.com/other-apps/lara2" the first page is ok but other routes throw 404 same as subdomain.
Main question: This method I'm trying to do with laravel, is it possible at all?

Goal: multi laravel apps at one shared host but only the app with public content in "public_html" is working fine.